What does マジだりいな mean in this Takayan song?

This line is from the song 演じてばかりだ by たかやん：
"おーおー マジだりいな"
Followed by :
"おーおー 眠りたくないな"
The official english translation says it means : "seriously a bore".

None of the proposed duplicates really seems to hit the mark. It would be better to have a clear canonical for this general sort of sound change, how to recognize them etc.

@KarlKnechtel The first four links generically mention the /ui/-to-/ii/ change found in "darui → darii". What's still missing?

It is a slurred version of おーおー マジ怠{だる}いな.
